# How to find symbols on a page and get a values between the two symbols in JS?

Tags: javascript, parsing

Some page have inserted secret text and JS script on this page should get a value between two characters, for example, between characters @@. In this variant @@569076@@ - 569076 should receive.

Here is what i've tried:

```
<div id="textDiv"></div>
<script>
    var markup = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");
    div.textContent = markup.match(/@@([^@]*)@@/);
    var text = div.textContent;
</script>
```

But nothing displayed

Comment: `string.match(/@@([^@]*)@@/)[1]`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I try code below, but nothing displayed.

<div id="textDiv"></div>
<script>
var markup = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");
div.textContent = markup.match(/@@([^@]*)@@/);
var text = div.textContent;
</script>

Comment: @Tushar thanks its work, but what if string have a spaces (56 90 76)?

Comment: Welcome @Astraport. The meaning of `[^@]*` is match until `@`. So, spaces won't cause any problem here.

Comment: This works fine for me, although the text content you assign will be the array returned by `match` coerced to a string, and will not find all the values you want because you are missing the `g` flag. If you are getting nothing, there is probably something else wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the match function returns an array of matched values and textContent will only accept a string.

So you have to select which array item you want to use for the textContent assignment:

```
div.textContent = markup.match(/@@(\d+)@@/)[1];
```

Note we selected the **first captured item** using the `[1]` from the matches array.

If the string has spaces in, just add a space in the list of matched items like so:

```
var markup =  '@@56 90 76@@';
alert( markup.match(/@@([\d ]*)@@/)[1]);
```

Comment: Make sure the code doesn't throw error `cannot read 1 of null`.

Comment: Your code throw error, but this work /@@([^@]*)@@/ - but not work if string have a space.

Comment: It's fine to assign an array to `textContent`. It will be coerced into a string.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your text/code into a variable.
You can replace body selector by yours.

Plain JS:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHtml,
    match = html.match(/@@(\d+)@@/),
    digits;

if (match) {
    digits = match[1];
}
```

if you are using jQuery and like shortands:

```
var digits, match;

if (match = $('body').html().match(/@@(\d+)@@/)) {
    digits = match[1];
}
```